# Div clickable in Rails with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a div in one of my Rails views that I would like to make fully clickable:

```
<% @objects.each do |f| %>
  <div class="overlay" >
    <%= link_to image_tag("play.png"), f %>
 </div>
```

How would I make the div class overlay follow the link_to the |f| object in jQuery? I found this in another StackOverflow question and I would like to customize it for the above scenario:

```
$('.overlay').click( function(event) {
  var clicked_div = $(this);
  # do stuff with the event object and 'this' which 
  # represent the element you just clicked on
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need it to be a div? Can you not use the link on its own and change its display property to block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving a class to the `a` tag?

```rb
<% @objects.each do |f| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("play.png"), f, class: 'overlay' %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This will end up creating something like

```
<a href='/some_address' class='overlay'><img src="play.png" alt="something" /></a>
```